# What is the fundamental difference of these two Aristotle books given their confusion non-modern titles?

Tags: aristotle

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_philosophy

> Aristotelian "physics" is different from what we mean today by this word, not only to the extent that it belongs to antiquity whereas the modern physical sciences belong to modernity, rather above all it is different by virtue of the fact that Aristotle's "physics" is philosophy, whereas modern physics is a positive science that presupposes a philosophy....

I wonder if this quote is talking about the actual book titled "Physics" from Aristotle. If that book is mainly philosophical, does that make the book "Physics" deserve a title like "Philosophy of Physics"?

What to make of Aristotle's book "MetaPhysics" then? Would that be better titled "Philosophy of MetaPhysics"?

I guess the main question is, what is the fundamental difference of these books given their confusion non-modern titles?

Comment: Your quote is just Heidegger's hermeneutics of suspicion reading of Aristotle's *Physics*, you can also use your own faith reading which is consistent with Heidegger's own remark later that without Aristotle's *Physics* there would have been no Galileo. In Aristotle's time it's not that easy or common to do intersubjectively aggreable positive physics due to communication and measurement technique restrictions, thus physics as science in modern demarcated sense wasn't much different from philosophy of physics conceivably and understandably...

Comment: Maybe you have to consider historical information... see [Physics (Aristotle)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physics_(Aristotle))

Comment: And see [Metaphysics (Aristotle)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphysics_(Aristotle))

Comment: The name have historical roots and there is nothing rilevant in fighting against tradition.  Meta- book is named so because deals with topic that are after (more fundamental than) topics discussed into Physics book.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA What are the most fundamental topics to you? What about information theory?